# C++ to .NET : I need help with understanding C++ code to convert it to .NET

Tags: c#, .net, c++, f#

C++ code is :

```
unsigned short* ui=(unsigned short*)&buf[110];
            CountDev=ui[0];
```

buf is `byte[]` and CountDev is `unsigned int`

(BCB6 Compiler x86)

My try is : 
F#

```
...CountDev  = System.BitConverter.ToInt32( [| arrayRead.[110]; arrayRead.[111] |] , 0 )
```

C#

```
...CountDev  = System.BitConverter.ToInt32( [arrayRead[110]; arrayRead[111]] , 0 )
```

But seriously I can't be sure about it. Check my try and tell me if I am doing it wrong please.

Comment: Your original C++ code relies on undefined behaviour...

Comment: "Can't be sure about it" is not a question. List the compiler errors or describe expected and actual results.

Comment: @Henk Holterman I want to convert the code proper. There is no errors but I'm not sure if my solution is making the same as C++ variant because I don't fully understand the byte way there. So the question is .NET variant of C++ code.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth why ? and so then I need to reproduce this undefined behavior somehow. If that is possible without invoking

Comment: @Oli, really? if you're talking about endianness, then it's not considered an undefined behaviour, and generally cannot be, because you don't know how `buf` was created, maybe it's a pointer to a real `unsigned char` array. Alignment is not meaningful for the same reason.

Comment: @unkulunkulu: Yeah, I was referring to pointer aliasing.  But you're right, it's possible that `buf` actually points to an array of `unsigned short`.  Although if I had to guess, I'd guess that it probably doesn't.

Comment: Buf is just an array of bytes. That's how I understand it. But I need to read this integer value exactly from same place and convert it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just do this to simply concatenate the two bytes and putting it into an int:

```
UInt32 CountDev = (UInt32)arrayRead[111] << 8 | (UInt32)arrayRead[110];
```

since you just need the least significant two byte, and int is 4 byte long (the most significant or sign bit is not touched), you can also use a signed int:

```
int CountDev = (int)arrayRead[111] << 8 | (int)arrayRead[110];
```

**Edit**:

Henk Holtermans solution is definitely the better choice as it uses the endianess of the current machine:

```
UInt32 CountDev = (UInt32)System.BitConverter.ToUint16(arrayRead, 110);
```

Comment: Isn't it just BitConvert.ToUInt16 realization with pushing Little endian ?

Comment: @Hans: youre right... was a little bit confused from the code the op provided: ``[arrayRead[110]; arrayRead[111]]``

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to use:

```
  ... = System.BitConverter.ToUint16(arrayRead, 110);
```

But it does depend on big/little endian (the order of the bytes in the array).
You will need specifications for that or a good test case.

Comment: but CountDev is unsigned int, so it must be 32 bit

Comment: @神田翠: just cast it to UInt32 afterwards

Comment: Yes, you need ToUint16 because you want to use exactly 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `System.BitConverter.ToUInt16` instead of `System.BitConverter.ToInt32`